# Mapping indices of vector elements

Tags: r, list

This is probably a trivial question.

Given a vector of characters, some of which are repeating:

```
vec <- c("a","b","d","e","e","f","g","a","d")
```

I'm looking for an **efficient** function that will return for each unique element in `vec` the indices of where it appears in `vec`.

I imagine that the return value would be something like this list:

```
list(a = c(1,8), b = 2, d = c(3,9), e = c(4,5), f = 6, g = 7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few options:

```
lapply(setNames(unique(vec),unique(vec)), function(x) which(x == vec) )
# or to avoid setNames and still ensure you get a list:
sapply(unique(vec), function(x) which(x == vec), simplify=FALSE)
# or even better but maybe not as extensible:
split(seq_along(vec),vec)
```

All giving:

```
$a
[1] 1 8

$b
[1] 2

$d
[1] 3 9

$e
[1] 4 5

$f
[1] 6

$g
[1] 7
```